# How to display the result in Django API

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, api

I just started working on python based Django. I am following this example to create an API.

https://dzone.com/articles/create-a-simple-api-using-django-rest-framework-in

Instead of using POSTMAN I am using my web browser to display the result bu I am getting error. Method 'GET' not allowed. 
I looked into different answers and concluded that I need to add a 'GET' method
I tried changing

@api_view(["POST"]) from 'POST'  to 'GET'

but then it throw an error "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)".

How can I add a GET here in this view.

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def IdealWeight(heightdata):
   try:
      height=json.loads(heightdata.body)
      weight=str(height*10)
      return JsonResponse("Ideal weight should be:"+weight+" kg",safe=False)
   except ValueError as e:
      return Response(e.args[0],status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Do I need POSTMAN to view the output?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Your Code indentation is wrong. Look at the blog again**. 
Your function IdealWeight expects a value which it tries to get (using `json.loads(heightdata.body)`) from your GET request's body. When you use a browser to do a GET request the body is empty. That can cause error or your `height` will be empty. 
If you just want to test the endpoint for GET change like this.

```py
@api_view(["GET"])
def IdealWeight(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    return Response({"Print": "GET request from browser works"}, status=status. HTTP_200_OK)
```

**You should use postman for testing POST request as it makes it easy**

Comment: Thanks so much. I fixed the indentation..It's working you have suggested but how can i get the  heightdata from url and process it to return the output? 
 There is no way to test it from the browser ? If  give  http://127.0.0.1:8000/idealweight/2.3  can it display 23 ? 
I tried doing it in flask where i was able to see it on the browser.

Comment: is your api browsable when you go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/idealweight/? If _yes_ then you can continue to use the POST request function and enter the data using the web UI form. If _no_ then you can get height using query paramenter ```height = int(request.query_params["height"])``` (instead of ```height=json.loads(heightdata.body)```) and a url like http://127.0.0.1:8000/idealweight/?height=23 with height value 23